# How to install PHP 5.2 compatible PHPUnit through composer?

Tags: php, phpunit, backwards-compatibility

This is for those who sticks with PHP5.2 and dont' need pear, but only composer.

Another more nice solutions are welcome.

But more adequate solution would be to just add those versions at packagist. Even with some tags like x.y.z-backwards. I just pray for it.

Comment: If you already have a copy and are just looking for how to make install quick and easy via composer, you can set up your own package repository to store it on, and point your composer to it.

Comment: @STLMikey It will require more steps to setup. I want something easy and obvious — just add something to composer.json and run update. And also to be available for all others.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://github.com/garex/phpunit and install this package.

Add to your composer:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit-php52": "dev-3.6.12-php52",
    "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects-php52": "dev-1.1.0-php52"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/garex/phpunit"
    },
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/garex/phpunit-mock-objects"
    }
]
```

Branches 3.6.12-php52 and 1.1.0-php52 are default at github repos, so they will be installed quick.